# How to set a exception in a xpath filter for a similar sounding word?

Tags: csv, exception, xpath, filter

I'm trying to import a large .csv file (60k entries) in one of my projects by using an importer tool. This tool allows me to filter the entries with the help of a xpath command, which is very useful, because I only need a few of these entries actually.

So I'm trying to filter the [title] element by looking for some keywords, that are relevant for me, but I ran into a problem, because my filter options seem to collide and I don't know how to implement the exception the right way.

The title element has for example values like:

> "[...]... house... [...]"

*or*

> "[...]... houseboat ... [...]"

but I only need the entries with "house" (but case insensitive, therefore I inserted "translate"), so my filter looks like:

```js
/node [title[1][contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),"house")]
```

But this condition of course also recognizes "**house**boat", is there a way to make an exception for some defined values?

Just adding

```js
and title[1][not(contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),"houseboat"))]
```

seems not to work, because this might be a contradiction...?

It's not consistent, at what position "house" occurs in the title, so it would not be a solution to check for "house " (with an empty space after or before it).

Is there any way to search for a word, but ignore a similar sounding one at the same time?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  I suggest that you [edit] it and remove references to "sounds like" unless you truly mean auditory similarly (in which case XPath cannot help you).  Then, add two explicit lists: **Should select** and **Should *not* select**, with multiple examples under for each.